# cargo run --example exaple_name causes "no example target named 'example_name'"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am studying the following [code](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs) and cannot wrap my head around why `cargo run --example abigen` wouldn't work. The docs state that package has to be specified like so `cargo run -p ethers --example abigen`. Indeed, this fixes the issue. But according to Rust docs, I should be able to use the first version. Why doesn't this first version work?

Comment: [This is a Cargo workspace](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/blob/master/Cargo.toml). Looks like it confuses Cargo somehow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#examples), files with a `main()` function can be called with `cargo run --example <example-name>`. That is to say, you can run an example of `examples/a.rs` by `cargo run --example a`. Back to the mentioned project, exmaples are actually individual sub-crates, thus can not be called like that.